# show label (add some data) when my table view is empty?

Tags: ios, tableview

I have one table view with an add button. When the user presses that add button I add data to the table view, but I when the table contains no data I want to show a label with a message:

> no data added

I am using core data. I have already tried some suggestion from Stack Overflow, but no solution helped.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

        nomatchesView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        nomatchesView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UILabel *matchesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,320)];
        matchesLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
        matchesLabel.minimumFontSize = 12.0f;
        matchesLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        matchesLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        matchesLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
        matchesLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        matchesLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        matchesLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        matchesLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

        //Here is the text for when there are no results
        matchesLabel.text = @"No Matches";


        nomatchesView.hidden = YES;
        [nomatchesView addSubview:matchesLabel];
        [self.tableView insertSubview:nomatchesView belowSubview:self.tableView];
    }



    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        //If there is no table data, unhide the "No  data added" view
        if(catefetchedResultsController == 0 ){
        nomatchesView.hidden = NO;
        } else {
        nomatchesView.hidden = YES;
        }

        return [data count];
    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you using a `UITableViewController` subclass or a `UIViewController` subclass with a table view added to the root view?

Comment: uiviewcontroller subclass with uitableview...

Comment: In that case I would add the label to the view rather than the tableview and hide the table view/unhide the label.  The other approach I have used is to populate a single row in the table with the message when the array count==0.  It depends on what you are looking for visually

Comment: can u show some code please . i am very beginner to ios

Comment: when user open my app ,if they not yet add any data to their table view  . A lable or image (anything) should show (hidden = NO).. After user add some data that label or image should be in hidden...i need that label or image as subview of table view.because i am not well gud in that subview parts..

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?  If so, add the label in your storyboard - your approach for setting hidden=true/false will work, but I think you are positioning the label incorrectly

Comment: yes i am using storyboard....

Answer (score 0):

Your View has to be the tableFooterView or tableHeaderView of the UITableView:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = noMatchesView
```